# Using admob banner ad and interstitial ad inside same activity

Tags: adsense, admob

I want to implement admob banner ad and interstitial ad inside same activity in following way:

Banner ad will be always displayed at bottom of activity and when user performs few action (suppose clicks next button) then interstitial is shown.

Is it against policy?

Currently I have two methods in my mind to implement this :

1) before showing interstitial ad load banner ad, them display interstitial. after interstitial is closed display banner ad again.

2) display interstitial ad in activity containg banner ad, without hiding banner ad.
Out of this two ways which one should i prefer?
Will it be against policy?

Comment: you can achieve it in same activity, as long as you follow the policy's mentioned by Google. For interstitial implementaiton follow this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in displaying banner ads as well as interstitial ads in the same Activity. Personally I would go with option (2) as it is simpler.

Comment: I have implemented option 2 in my apps: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epfbalanceandclaimstatus.aseelzameer.epfbalanceclaimstatus